Material React Table Lagging in Chrome but Smooth in Firefox
I'm building a table with Material React Table with Vite+swc. Everying is up-to-date.
I was working with Firefox and in development I did not notice anything but my client told me that the table is slow and laggy. They use Chrome, so I checked the demo in Chrome on Material React Table's official website: https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/virtualized#virtualized-demo.
I am using virtualization too, just like they in this demo. In Chrome it does not feel as smooth as in Firefox.
Did anyone else encounter the same issue? Seems like Chrome has a bit of an issue dealing with this many transform translate in long td's or something.
Here is a screenshot in Chrome's Performance tab if it helps
Chrome Performance Screenshot
Tried with memeMode: "rows" the rows. Ended up with over 600 MB of memory usage for this tab. Tho it did help with the scrolling :D
Looking for this issue I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/46807253/24077129 this issue where they suggested to force Chrome to use optimized rendering. I put this in the index.css for all table element, but it did not help, so I am stuck right now.

Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question and not a poll. Also take the [tour].

did you figure this out? @dingidango ??
